# wHY Wrong variable value while implementing DLL

Tags: c++, dll, dllimport

I was trying to implement DLL ..
The header file was

```
class calculate
  { 
    int a1;
    int b1;
  public:
    calculate(){ this->b1=10; this->a1=20;}
    int sum();
 };

namespace WRITER
  {
    WRITER_API calculate* getObject();
  }
```

But when this function was called from other program using DLL, It gave a error. 
Whatever value I was assigning to 'b1' was received in 'a1' and 'b1' was not getting initialized .... i.e. a was 10 and b wasn't initialized and it's value was -33686019 .

Where I'm making the mistake . !!

---

The code for getObject is like this ..

```
  calculate*  WRITER::getObject()
  {
    calculate *c =new calculate();
    return c;
    //return (calculate*) calculate::getObject;
  }
```

// I did this on this on other project, that was importing the DLL

```
calculate *c=WRITER::getObject();
int value=c->sum();
```

and error was on second line ..

Comment: Unrelated: There are a handful of header file names you *don't* want to use. [`math.h`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math) would be one of them.

Comment: I've changed the file names, still it didn't worked .!

Comment: How did you assign values to those variables? Outside that constructor?

Comment: I did this on the on other project, that was using DLL 
 `calculate *c=WRITER::getObject();
 int value=c->sum();`
Error was on second line .. !

Comment: Can you show us the definition of `calculate.sum()`, please? I just see a declaration there...

Comment: `int calculate::sum(){
    return a1+b1;
  }`

Comment: -33686019 is a magic number in the VS crt, 0xfdfdfdfd means that you are referencing memory that's not part of the allocated heap block.  More evidence that the pointer returned by getObject() is off by 4.  This mishap cannot occur with the code you posted, the *actual* object returned by getObject() is not the *calculate* class, it is another one that has a v-table pointer.  So the compiler sees the wrong class definition when it compiles the client code.  You avoid this kind of mishap by declaring the publicly visible type as an interface instead.

Comment: I too understand that, that there was off by 4, because b's value was going to a, but why it was happening , I don't know.. but code was exactly the same, then did the same thing which you told, I made a interface and It worked >! ....
There must be some mistake that I've made ...But yes it's working for now ..!!